# Load suggestions in Autocomplete component only on input change

Tags: material-ui

I fetch my autocomplete suggestions from my db, and I do that whenever the input changes, the problem is my function triggers every time my value changes as well (because that triggers an input change I guess), which is really inefficient and causes a lot of network requests on rerenders, how can I prevent that ?

My code looks something like this.

```
const handleValueChange = (event, newValue) =>{
  setValue(newValue);
}

const handleInputChange = (event, newInput) =>{
  // Fetching and setting suggestions here
  ...
 setInput(newInput);
}

<Autocomplete
       value={value}
       onChange={handleValueChange}
       inputValue={input}
       onInputChange={handleInputChange}
       ....
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say look into using the useEffect hook in combination with state. Something along the line of

```
const [suggestions,setSuggestions] = useState();

useEffect(()=>{ //fetch and set suggestions },[]}
```

then set the options in the autocomplete to the state you just set. Making sure you conditional render the autocomplete to not display before fetching is done.

```
{suggestions? (<AutoComplete.../>):("")}
```

I don't know if you can use this line for line, but at least in the right direction.